# How to give different colors to parts of the main of a plot

Tags: r, colors, program-entry-point

I simply represent the curves of Average Total Costs, Average Variable Costs, Average Fixed Costs and Marginal Costs.

```
plot(Q,ATCosts,ylab=NA,ylim=c(0,62),type="l")
par(new=T)
plot(Q,AVCosts,ylab=NA,ylim=c(0,62),type="l",col="blue")
par(new=T)
plot(Q,AFCosts,ylab=NA,ylim=c(0,62),type="l",col="red")
par(new=T)
plot(Q,MCosts,ylab=NA,ylim=c(0,62),type="l",col="green")
```

The main is:

```
title(main="ATC,AVC,AFC,MC")
```

What I would like to know is if there is a way to give each piece of the main (containing a certain type of cost) the color related to that cost in the plot, in order to avoid to use a legend. Thus, ATC must be written in black; AVC must be written in blue...and so on.

I tried to overlap another title in the following way:

```
title(main="   ,AVC,   ,  ",col.main="blue")
```

But it didn't give a decent result.

Comment: First of all, try using `lines` instead of `par(new=T);plot()` .  I don't believe `main` allows multiple colors, but you could always use `text` judiciously to place multiple character strings w/ different colors in the "title area"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a general solution, because you have to play with the `adj` to get the right spacing, but it works:

```
plot(1)
mtext("ATC, ",col='black',line=2,adj=0.4)
mtext("AVC, ",col='blue',line=2,adj=0.45)
mtext("AFC, ",col='red',line=2,adj=0.5)
mtext("MC",col='green',line=2,adj=0.54)
```

[image]

Comment: Might I suggest more general solution : `nn <- colnames(dat)-1]; Map(function(x,y,z)mtext(text=x,col=y,adj=z,line=2),
       nn,rainbow(length(nn)),seq(0.4,by=0.05,length.out=length(nn)))`

Comment: @agstudy Nice. I think a more important improvement would be to calculate the string widths and use exact adjustments to get the spacing right for strings in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a legend, you can use `directLables` package. But you should use move to some high level plot package (lattice/ggplot2)

[image]

```
set.seed(10)
dat = data.frame(Q= factor(paste0('Q',1:12)),
AT = runif(12,1,100),
                 AV = runif(12,1,100),
                 AF = runif(12,1,100),
                 MC = runif(12,1,100))


library(lattice)
library(directlabels)

p <- xyplot(AT+AV+AF+MC~Q,data=dat,type='l')

direct.label(p,"first.qp")
```